# ExtJS tab header width

Tags: extjs, tabs

I faced the following problem: 
I'm using ExtJS tabpanel control and I want the tab headers to span the whole container, ie - if there are two tabs, their tab headers width should be 50% of the tabpanel width. I can't manage to do this. 
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Just apply this

```
tabBar: {
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    defaults: { flex: 1 }
},
```

to your tabpanel configuration.

> Note: This will only work for tabPosition 'top' and 'bottom'!